# How to save the edited features on a layer back to PostGIS table?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I have PostGIS + OpenLayers + GeoServer. I have developed an app which can show layers from PostGIS DB, allow user to edit, add, view features on a vector layer. Now, my need is to save the edited or newly created features back to PostGIS DB.

Is it possible to achieve it using only OpenLayers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Geoserver's WFS-T (for transactional) functionality and how to use it in OpenLayers. There should be some Q&A on this topic on this site already.